# Renaming files sequentially from folder name with Automator

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, macos

Asked previously about renaming files in a folder ([Rename File(s) from Foldername using automator/AppleScript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/424361/37797)), and now I have a folder flow that almost works.

I have created a folder in my Downloads called DOIT (As per attachments and workflow screenshots).
I drop a folder in there called "Race Track 2019" which has a few random filenames in.

What I want is to rename the files sequentially from the folder name. I have the folder name variable working (as per screenshots) but it won't rename the files.

I was after (in this example) to be left with 2 files called "Race Track 2019-1 and Race Track 2019-2"

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

### Using Automator for the Folder Action

In the **Automator** *Folder Action* image further below in this answer, pay attention to the **Automator** *actions* and their settings. In particular, the **Options** set on the **Get Value of Variable** *action* has **[√] Ignore this action's input** checked.

The first *action*, **Set Value of Variable**, is set to `IncomingFolder` and gets filtered in a **Filter Finder Items** *action* so as to get just the *folder* itself in order to use a **Run Shell Script** *action* to ascertain its `name` and assign it to the `FolderName` *variable* in the **Set Value of Variable** *action*.

There needs to be a logical break between this **Set Value of Variable** *action* and the ensuing **Get Value of Variable** *action* so as to then filter out the *folder(s)* as it's the *files* that will be renamed, not the *folder(s)*.

The image shown further below in this answer is of the actual working **Automator** *Folder Action* and why there is no **Get Selected Finder Items** *action* nor and *green circle check marks*, as it is run in the *background* when the **Race Track 2019** *folder* is dropped into the **DOIT** *folder.*

In my testing:

```
Race Track 2019
├── cb4d4gdc.jpg
└── nn49494.jpg
```

Became:

```
Race Track 2019
├── Race Track 2019-1.jpg
└── Race Track 2019-2.jpg
```

---

### Using an AppleScript script for the Folder Action

Here is another approach that uses an **AppleScript** *script* for the **Folder Action**.

One of its benefits is it can handle multiple *folders* being dropped at the same time into the target *folder* of the **Folder Action**.

Using **Script Editor**, save the *example* **AppleScript** *code*  to **~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts** and use **Folder Action Setup** to assign it to the target *folder*.

[image]

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
on adding folder items to thisFolder after receiving theseNewItems
    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with thisItem in theseNewItems
            set thisItemsProperties to properties of thisItem
            if class of thisItemsProperties is folder then
                set folderName to name of thisItemsProperties
                set theseFiles to files of entire contents of thisItem
                repeat with i from 1 to count theseFiles
                    set name of item i of theseFiles to ¬
                        folderName & "-" & i & "." & ¬
                        name extension of item i of theseFiles
                end repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, as coded, assumes *files* to be renamed have an *extension*. If you need to act on *files* not having an *extension*, then the *example* **AppleScript** *code* will need to be modified to accommodate that condition.

---

### **Screenshot of Automator Folder Action**

**Note:** This **Automator** *Folder Action* is designed to receive a single *folder* at a time!

Dropping multiple *folders* will result in the all *files* having the *name* of the first *folder* dropped!

For multiple *folders*, see: **Using an AppleScript script for the Folder Action**

[image]

---

### As an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* for Finder

If you'd like you be able to select *folders* in **Finder** and have the *files* within renamed, then create an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* with the settings as shown in the image of the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* below, adding a **Run AppleScript** *action* with the *example* **AppleScript** *code*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    
    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with thisItem in input
            set folderName to name of thisItem
            set theseFiles to files of entire contents of thisItem
            repeat with i from 1 to count theseFiles
                set name of item i of theseFiles to ¬
                    folderName & "-" & i & "." & ¬
                    name extension of item i of theseFiles
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
    
end run
```

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, as coded, assumes *files* to be renamed have an *extension*. If you need to act on *files* not having an *extension*, then the *example* **AppleScript** *code* will need to be modified to accommodate that condition.

[image]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain, AppleScript seems better for my use so I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact - if you do this *slightly* wrong in Automator, you can end up renaming **every file** on your computer. I might have done it more than slightly wrong, but (if I ever finish reinstalling my OS) I don't think I'll test my theory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).